# Make Rails' number_to_percentage output a dynamic count of decimals, based on the input value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to use Rails' [`number_to_percentage`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_percentage) method to display a decimal number that I have in the range 0 to 100 as a percentage, including all of the number's decimal digits, and no unnecessary trailing zeroes.

Some example inputs and their corresponding desired outputs:

```
12        => "12%"
12.3      => "12.3%"
12.34     => "12.34%"
12.345    => "12.345%"
12.3456   => "12.3456%"
```

As the documentation states, `number_to_percentage` has a default precision of 3, so `number_to_percentage(12.3456)` yields `"12.346%"` instead of my desired value.  Similarly, `number_to_percentage(12)` yields `"12.000%"` instead of just `"12%"`.

I've experimented with combinations of different values for the `precision`, `significant`, and `strip_insignificant_zeroes` options to `number_to_percentage`, but without getting it to yield my desired results.

Is there a way a use `number_to_percentage` such that it yields my desired results?  Or is this not the intended function of `number_to_percentage`, and I should take a different approach -- such as simply appending `'%'` to the end of my input using basic string manipulation?

Comment: `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_percentage(12.1234, precision: 4)` gives the desired result. I guess you can use `.to_s.split(".")[-1].length` to find the precision number.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the suggestion, I agree, as the desired outputs are strings, not numbers. Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the precision to a number higher than you'll need and also setting strip_insignificant_zeros to true gives the desired results:

```
number_to_percentage 12, precision: 100, strip_insignificant_zeros: true
#=> "12%"

number_to_percentage 12.3, precision: 100, strip_insignificant_zeros: true
#=> "12.3%"

number_to_percentage 12.34, precision: 100, strip_insignificant_zeros: true
#=> "12.34%"

number_to_percentage 12.345, precision: 100, strip_insignificant_zeros: true
#=> "12.345%"

number_to_percentage 12.3456, precision: 100, strip_insignificant_zeros: true
#=> "12.3456%"
```

Comment: In my Rails 5.2.1 console, testing this solution using `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_percentage(12.3456, precision:20, strip_insignificant_zeroes:true)` yields `"12.34560000000000000000%"`. Does the behavior differ based on the Rails version? Or does something else account for the difference?

Comment: I see the issue. You are incorrectly using `strip_insignificant_zeroes`. The actual name of the option is `strip_insignificant_zeros`.

Comment: !!!!! That was exactly the problem. Thank you! I guess I should have hit https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/what-is-the-plural-form-of-zero before hitting StackOverflow. :-p

Answer (score 2):

First you need to determine how many digits are after the decimal.  You can do so using the following:

```
precision= n.to_s.partition('.').last.size
```

You can then set the precision value you want.

```
number_to_percentage(num, precision: precision)
```

Comment: Interesting approach! This doesn't work for the `12` input, though, because `"12".split('.').last.size` yields `2` (not `0`), and thus a final result of `12.00%`.

Comment: @JonSchneider one can change this to `12.to_s.partition('.').last.size`